# What layoutManager should I use?

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I'm creating an application to test system trays, but I don't know what layoutmanager I should use to make it look like this:

[image]

The problem I'm having is that I can't align the text in the textField vertically, so I thought something like: "Why not use layoutmanagers and make it scale with the message." What do you think about this?

Comment: Have you read the [Visual guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)?

Comment: Yes, I read it, but I didn't quite found the manager I wanted or I wasn't able to get it look like the image.

Comment: Use a combination of layouts. BorderLayout for the overall, with JLabel in the PAGE_START position and your JScrollPane/JTextArea in the CENTER position. And a FlowLayout.RIGHT using JPanel in the PAGE_END position holding the JButton.

Comment: I'd probably use a SpringLayout / BorderLayout, but that's because I draw equivalents to simple Android layouts with those.

Comment: To wrap words in your JTextArea, call the methods, `setWrapStyleWord(true)` and `setLineWrap(true)` on your JTextArea. Please see edit to my answer for an example.

Answer (score 4):

Simple: Use a combination of layouts. BorderLayout for the overall, with JLabel in the PAGE_START position and your JScrollPane/JTextArea in the CENTER position. And a FlowLayout.RIGHT using JPanel in the PAGE_END position holding the JButton.

e.g.,

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FooPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final String PROMPT = "This is prompt text:";
    private static final int TA_ROWS = 10;
    private static final int TA_COLS = 30;
    private static final int GAP = 5; 

    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(TA_ROWS, TA_COLS);

    public FooPanel() {
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.RIGHT));
        bottomPanel.add(new JButton("Submit"));

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(GAP, GAP));
        add(new JLabel(PROMPT), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        FooPanel mainPanel = new FooPanel();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("FooPanel");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}
```

Alternatively, the bottom JPanel could use BoxLayout with horizontal glue pushing the button over:

```
        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        bottomPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        bottomPanel.add(new JButton("Submit"));
```

An example using the above in a modal dialog, and showing how to wrap lines in your JTextArea:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class FooPanel extends JPanel {
    private static final int TA_ROWS = 10;
    private static final int TA_COLS = 30;
    private static final int GAP = 5;

    private JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea(TA_ROWS, TA_COLS);

    public FooPanel(String prompt) {
        textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        textArea.setLineWrap(true);

        JPanel bottomPanel = new JPanel();
        bottomPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(bottomPanel, BoxLayout.LINE_AXIS));
        bottomPanel.add(Box.createHorizontalGlue());
        bottomPanel.add(new JButton(new SendAction("Send", KeyEvent.VK_S)));

        setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(GAP, GAP, GAP, GAP));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout(GAP, GAP));
        add(new JLabel(prompt), BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        add(new JScrollPane(textArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(bottomPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    public String getText() {
        return textArea.getText();
    }

    private class SendAction extends AbstractAction {
        public SendAction(String name, int mnemonic) {
            super(name);
            putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, mnemonic); // alt-key shortcut mnemonic
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // simply dispose of this window
            Window win = SwingUtilities.getWindowAncestor(FooPanel.this);
            win.dispose();
        }
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        String prompt = "Enter the text that is to be displayed in the tray:";
        final FooPanel mainPanel = new FooPanel(prompt);

        final JFrame frame = new JFrame("FooPanel");
        final JTextArea displayArea = new JTextArea(TA_ROWS, TA_COLS);
        displayArea.setFocusable(false);
        displayArea.setEditable(false);
        displayArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        displayArea.setLineWrap(true);

        final JDialog dialog = new JDialog(frame, "Enter Text", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        dialog.add(mainPanel);
        dialog.pack();

        JPanel framePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        framePanel.add(new JScrollPane(displayArea), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        framePanel.add(new JPanel() {
            {
                add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Show Dialog") {
                    {
                        putValue(MNEMONIC_KEY, KeyEvent.VK_S);
                    }

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        dialog.setLocationRelativeTo(frame);
                        dialog.setVisible(true);

                        String text = mainPanel.getText();
                        displayArea.setText(text);
                    };
                }));
            }
        }, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(framePanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            createAndShowGui();
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use `BorderLayout`.

The simplest program I could come up with, to meet your needed positioning requirements is this:

```
public class PutText extends JFrame {

    public PutText() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        initGUI();
        pack();

        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    }

    private void initGUI() {
        Container cp = getContentPane();
        cp.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 10));

        JPanel upper = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JPanel lower = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());

        cp.add(upper, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        cp.add(lower, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);

        JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Put the text you want the tray to show.");
        JTextArea ta = new JTextArea();
        ta.setLineWrap(true);
        JButton btn = new JButton("Send");

        upper.add(lbl, BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        cp.add(ta, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        lower.add(btn, BorderLayout.LINE_END);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new PutText().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

}
```

Note that you would need to add the empty borders to resemble the program you want to create.

Comment: This is nice, but I like the frame dimensions I had. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @xX4m4zingXx: The "frame dimensions" should be dictated by the size of the text component itself. If using a JTextArea, then this is achieved by setting the JTextArea's row and column properties.

Comment: Sure thing, set the dimensions the way you like. I was just trying to show how to position elements simply.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels You mean like: when the text inside the JTextArea gets bigger than the JTextArea's dimensions then it should get bigger? and Dinomarion10 I thought already you were showing that, Thanks.

Comment: @xX4m4zingXx: Yes, that would happen. Note that JTextArea has a constructor that takes two ints, the first that specifies the number of rows it should display and the second the number of columns. Play with those numbers to get the size you want, remember to pack() any window before displaying it, and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Okay, Thanks. I think that this looks fine: http://prntscr.com/aerlqp , but when I'm typing and the text goes out of the screen it doesn't go to the next line. Is this normal?

Comment: Yes. Use `ta.setLineWrap(true);`

Comment: @xX4m4zingXx: you also need to call `ta.setWrapStyleWord(true)` so that the "lines will be wrapped at word boundaries" (per the [JTextArea API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTextArea.html)).

Answer (score 0):

One of the best Layout Manager that I use 1st GridBagLayout its more flexible to set the location of your Palette (Swing Containers, Controls)

```
public class GridBagLayoutSample {
JFrame frame = new JFrame("GridBagSample");
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
JButton btn1 = new JButton("One");
JButton btn2 = new JButton("Two");
JButton btn3 = new JButton("Three");
JButton btn4 = new JButton("Four");
JButton btn5 = new JButton("Five");
public GridBagLayoutSample(){
panel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
GridBagConstraints a = new GridBagConstraints();
a.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
a.insets = new Insets(3,3,3,3);

a.gridx = 0;
a.gridy = 0;
panel.add(btn1, a);

a.gridx = 1;
a.gridy = 0;
panel.add(btn2, a);

a.gridx = 0;
a.gridy = 1;
panel.add(btn3, a);


a.gridx = 1;
a.gridy = 1;
panel.add(btn4, a);


frame.add(panel);
frame.setVisible(true);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.pack();
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));

panel.setSize(300,300);
}
public static void main(String[] args) {
GridBagLayoutSample a = new GridBagLayoutSample();
}
```

Check this documentation. It explain here how GridBagLayout used. This is the best layout that I used because you can locate any position you want. Use Quadrants as your guide so will not get confused positioning your component hope this helps.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html

Comment: I'll take a look at it thank you. I think that layout managers are preferably, or not?

Comment: I prefer this layout manager. Its more flexible than free design. The most common layout that I used is Border,Flow and GridBag Layout. And try to look at Card Layout for transision of panels. If this help you vote me up.